# Waf - How to add a library to a wscript file?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, wsh, waf

I would like to add the c++ library cpp-netlib to a wscript.
Then if I run `dpkg -l libcppnetlib0` I obtain:

```
libcppnetlib0: 0.11.0-1     amd64        C++ Network Library
```

Running: `dpkg -L libcppnetlib0`, I obtain:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cppnetlib-uri.so.0.11.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cppnetlib-server-parsers.so.0.11.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cppnetlib-client-connections.so.0.11.0
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libcppnetlib0
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libcppnetlib0
/usr/share/doc/libcppnetlib0/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libcppnetlib0/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppnetlib-server-parsers.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppnetlib-client-connections.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppnetlib-uri.so.0
```

Since I need `libcppnetlib-uri, libcppnetlib-server-parsers, libcppnetlib-client-connections` , in the wscript I add the following fields:

```
conf.check_cxx(lib='cppnetlib-uri',uselib_store='CPPNETLIBU', define_name='HAVE_CPPNETLIBU',mandatory=True)
conf.check_cxx(lib='cppnetlib-server-parsers',uselib_store='CPPNETLIBS', define_name='HAVE_CPPNETLIBS',mandatory=True)
conf.check_cxx(lib='cppnetlib-client-connections',uselib_store='CPPNETLIBC', define_name='HAVE_CPPNETLIBC',mandatory=True)
```

Then I added the three references (CPPNETLIBU, CPPNETLIBC, CPPNETLIBS) here:

```
libndn_cxx = dict(
        target="ndn-cxx",
        name="ndn-cxx",
        source=bld.path.ant_glob('src/**/*.cpp',
                                 excl=['src/security/**/*-osx.cpp',
                                       'src/**/*-sqlite3.cpp']),
        headers='src/common-pch.hpp',
        use='version BOOST CRYPTOPP OPENSSL SQLITE3 RT PTHREAD CPPNETLIBC CPPNETLIBU CPPNETLIBS',
        includes=". src",
        export_includes="src",
        install_path='${LIBDIR}')
```

But, when I launch ./waf configure, it fails, it does not find the libraries that I specified.

The error is:

```
[199/200] Linking build/examples/clientMat
examples/clientMat.cpp.2.o: In function `construct<boost::network::http::impl::normal_delegate, asio::io_service&>':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ext/new_allocator.h:120: undefined reference to `boost::network::http::impl::normal_delegate::normal_delegate(asio::io_service&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppnetlib-client-connections.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppnetlib-client-connections.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I (maybe?) identified the problem in the absence of any reference in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig. Indeed, running: `ls /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, I have some `.pc` files but nothing about cppnetlib. I tried to write my own without success.

If the problem is here, actually I need an help about how to write the `.pc` files correctly.

This question was a good starting point, but I did not success the same: [waf -how to add external library to wscript_build file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016448/waf-how-to-add-external-library-to-wscript-build-file)

Comment: The process of adding a library dependency to a wscript file is correct as reported above. Given the lack of documentation, this question could be useful. The problem of the question was the missing of another extra library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **bld.read_shlib()** as described in https://waf.io/book/

example code (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf("cos(0.123456)=%f\n", cos(0.123456));
    return 0;
}
```

build script using math library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

top = '.'
out = 'build'

VERSION = '0.0.0'
APPNAME = 'app'

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
    conf.load('compiler_c')
    conf.check_cc(lib='m', cflags='-Wall', uselib_store='M')
    conf.check(header_name='math.h', features='c cprogram')

def build(bld):
    bld.read_shlib('m')
    bld.program(target='app', source='main.c')
```

Comment: would someone care to explain how this magicc works? (waf is quite poorly documented, so most commands are quite counterintuitive for a beginner)